# How can I prevent the "console.log()" function from being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I need a way to prevent `console.log()` from being changed/overwritten (ex: `console.log = function(){ return "Hi" }`. At first, I tried `Object.freeze(console.log)` but this did not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.defineProperty` to make the property non-writable and non-configurable:

```js
Object.defineProperty(console, 'log', { value: console.log, writable: false, configurable: false });

// Below won't work now, and will throw in strict mode:
console.log = () => null;

console.log('foobar');
```

You may also wish to make `window.console` non-overwritable as well:

```js
Object.defineProperty(console, 'log', { value: console.log, writable: false, configurable: false });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', { value: console, writable: false, configurable: false });

// Below won't work now, and will throw in strict mode:
console.log = () => null;
// Below won't work either:
window.console = { dir: () => null };

console.log('foobar');
console.log('barbaz');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can freeze the object console instead of the attribute. `Object.freeze(console)`